# Fatal error: num rows

Tags: php

I have this error:

> Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '1000' reached, aborting! in C:\xampp\htdocs\progettoPersonale\libs\DbConnector.php on line 47

I have two classes, however when I try to know the number of rows me error

```
<?php
class UserModel
{
    private $dbconn = null ;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->dbconn = new DbConnector();
    }


    public function checkLogin($username, $password ){

     $new_password=password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $res =$this->dbconn->select(
        array('*'),
        'iscritti',
        "nome_utente='".$this->dbconn->escape($username)."' && password='".$this->dbconn->escape($new_password)."'"
    );
        $resault =$this->dbconn->num_rows($res);

        if($resault==1){

            return true ;
        }else{
            return false ;
        }
    }
}
<?php

class DbConnector
{  private $_dbconn = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_dbconn= new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
    }

    public function select( $fields, $table, $conditions = '1' ) {
        $query = "SELECT ";
        $query .= implode( ', ', $fields );
        $query .= " FROM ";
        $query .= $table;
        $query .= " WHERE ";
        $query .= $conditions;

        var_dump($query);
        return $this->_dbconn->query($query);
    }
    public function insert($table,$fields,$values){
        $query = "INSERT INTO" .$table."";
        $query.= "(".implode(',', $fields).")";
        $query.= "VALUES" ;
        $query.= "(".implode(',', $values).")";

        return $this->_dbconn->query($query);
    }

    public function fetch_assoc($res){
        return $res->fetch_assoc();
    }
    public function query($query){
        return $this->_dbconn->query($query);
    }
    public  function escape($string){
        return $this->_dbconn->real_escape_string($string);
    }
    public function last_id(){
        return $this->last_id();
    }
    public function num_rows(){
        return $this->num_rows();
    }
    public function close_con(){
        $this->close_con();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`num_rows` calls itself.

```
public function num_rows(){
    return $this->num_rows();
}
```

It will just keep calling itself until you hit this error. Did you maybe mean this?

```
public function num_rows($res){
    return $res->num_rows;
}
```

Comment: You also have the same issue on `last_id()` and `close_con()`.

Comment: thanks for the help I coretto the mistakes that I have reported but now I find myself another mistake:public function num_rows($res){
        return $res->num_rows();
    }( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::num_rows() in C:\xampp\htdocs\progettoPersonale\libs\DbConnector.php on line 48
( ! ) Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::num_rows() in C:\xampp\htdocs\progettoPersonale\libs\DbConnector.php on line 48

Comment: @GiulianoCortesi `num_rows` is a variable, not a function. Remove the brackets at the end.